# Prometheus + snmp_exporter regex

Tags: regex, prometheus, grafana, snmp

I have Dell servers with iDrac 8. Monitoring: Prometheus+snmp_exporter+Grafana.
MIB: iDRAC-SMIv2
OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.5.4.300.40.1.8

From SNPP I get eventLogDateName in format: 20201222152131.000000+120
How can I use regex for replace 20201222152131.000000+120 to 12/22/20 15:21:31. I don't know where is I need insert my regex.

P.S.

```
pattern = '^(?P<YYYY>\d{4})(?P<MM>\d{2})(?P<DD>\d{2})(?P<HH>\d{2})(?P<mm>\d{2})(?P<ss>\d{2})\.(?P<SSSSSS>\d{6})(?P<ZZ>[-+]\d{3,4})$'
replacement = "${YYYY}-${MM}-${DD} ${HH}:${mm}:${ss}"
```

Comment: Not sure about the named capture groups, but you can split the match for the year in 2 groups of 2 digits, and then replace with the group numbers `$1/$2/$3 $4:$5:$6` https://regex101.com/r/xDLuij/1

Comment: Review: your Q could use a bit mnore formatting, consider using code blocks and formatting to highlight background and question better.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I need to specify regular expressions and replacements where in the configuration. What parameters should be specified in generator.yml or snmp.yml

Comment: ?P in your pattern looks not like regex. also your replacement is a mixture of regex and formatting syntax. check e.g. this online regex: filled in infos from your question https://regexr.com/5lcni

Comment: I was added regex pattern as an example. Don't mind this. I am interested in the functionality of Prometheus or snmp_exporter